# How to include properly Javascript using a Javascript Twig Template

Tags: javascript, symfony, templates, twig

I know how to access my assets, but i wanted to create a template working with Javascript and Twig, which would allow me to use Twig variables in my script.

For example, I have a template called 'details.html.twig', which extends a 'layout.html.twig':

```
{% extends '@AcmeBundle/Front/layout.html.twig %}
{# SOME CODE AND CONTENT #}


{% block page_script %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <script>
    {# Part of my script #}
  </script>
{% endblock page_script %}
```

All of this worked perfectly, but to be able to reuse some js code (using twig variables), I cut some part of my script and put I in an external template, called 'viewer.html.twig'. To be able to use it in my 'details.html.twig', I used:

```
{% include '@AcmeBundle/Front/Model/viewer.html.twig' %}
```

I put this line right after the {{ parent() }} one and before the `<script>` tag.
However, my script which used to work when directly written in 'details' template seems to be quite ignored right now.

If any of you could have a clue of what makes my template being included but skipped, or a way to include the template easier or properly, I'm open to all kind of observations.

G'day,
Jérémy

Comment: Wrap your code inside `viewer.html.twig` in block tags, then where you want to include it call `{{ block('my_custom_block_name') }}`

Answer (score 1):

If you code a file containing only javascript you should name your file:

`{% include '@AcmeBundle/Front/Model/viewer.js.twig' %}`

Then Twig (as of 1.17) automatically defines its escaping strategy based on the extension.

See the [twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options) and an example of [js twig file in symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/base_js.html.twig).